# Select / Deselect Items in multiple listboxes based on selection of an item in one listbox - C# Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a scenario where I have three listboxes. Multiple Items can be selected in the listboxes.
Based on the selection of items in one listbox, I need to select and deselect the corresponding rows in the other listboxes.

I have the code below, but I am missing something.
When I select and deselecting the item, it selects and deselects the other rows items incorrectly.

```
            for (int count = 0; count < listBox_1.SelectedIndices.Count; count++)
            {
                // Determine if the item is selected.
                if (listBox_1.GetSelected(count) == true)
                {
                    listBox_2.SetSelected(listBox_1.SelectedIndices[count], false);
                    listBox_3.SetSelected(listBox_1.SelectedIndices[count], false);
                }
                else if (listBox_1.GetSelected(count) == false)
                {
                    // Select all items that are not selected.
                    listBox_2.SetSelected(listBox_1.SelectedIndices[count], true);
                    listBox_3.SetSelected(listBox_1.SelectedIndices[count], true);
                }

            }
```

Here Selection of items in LB1 should control the selection in LB2 and LB3.
Now, since Item 2 and 3 are selected in LB1 - items 2 and 3 should be selected in LB2 and LB3 as well. But that's not what's happening.

[image]

## ========================================
UPDATE

How do I replicate the behavior when the user selects the items in ListBox2 or ListBox3

```
    private void listBox_1_SelectedIndexChanged_(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox_2.ClearSelected();
        listBox_3.ClearSelected();

        int userSelectedIndex = listBox_1.Items.Count;
        if (listBox_1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < listBox_1.Items.Count; count++)
            {
                // Determine if the item is selected.
                if (listBox_1.GetSelected(count) == true)
                {
                    if (count <= listBox_2.Items.Count)
                        listBox_2.SetSelected(count, true);
                    if (count <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                        listBox_3.SetSelected(count, true);
                }
                else if (listBox_1.GetSelected(count) == false)
                {
                    // Select all items that are not selected.
                    if (count <= listBox_2.Items.Count)
                        listBox_2.SetSelected(count, false);
                    if (count <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                        listBox_3.SetSelected(count, false);
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

WHEN users selects items in ListBox 2, items in LB1 and LB3 should be selected as well.

```
    private void listBox_2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox_1.ClearSelected();  // ITS giving error here.
        listBox_3.ClearSelected(); 
           
        int userSelectedIndex = listBox_2.Items.Count;
        if (listBox_2.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < listBox_2.Items.Count; count++)
            {
                // Determine if the item is selected.
                if (listBox_2.GetSelected(count) == true)
                {
                    if (count <= listBox_1.Items.Count)
                        listBox_1.SetSelected(count, true);
                    if (count <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                        listBox_3.SetSelected(count, true);
                }
                else if (listBox_2.GetSelected(count) == false)
                {
                    // Select all items that are not selected.
                    if (count <= listBox_1.Items.Count)
                        listBox_1.SetSelected(count, false);
                    if (count <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                        listBox_3.SetSelected(count, false);
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: _”but I am missing something.”_ … is not a question. What is not working as expected?

Comment: @JohnG - Updated - It's selecting and deselecting the other row items incorrectly.

Comment: OK I think that is a little clearer. What would be considered “correct” when the user selects/un-selects a row in list box 1? And what would be considered “incorrect”? We have no idea what determines which list box row(s) should be selected/un-selected when another row in another list box is selected/un-selected. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @JohnG - Updated an example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Or simply use a `foreach` loop through the `SelectedIndicies` collection. Something like... `foreach (int selectedIndex in listBox_1.SelectedIndices) { ...` ... Where is the posted code getting called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear where this code is called. I would simply clear the other list2 and list3 boxes and then set the same selected indexes as the ones in list box 1... some thing like...

```
listBox_2.ClearSelected();
listBox_3.ClearSelected();
foreach (int selectedItem in listBox_1.SelectedIndices) {
  listBox_2.SetSelected(selectedItem, true);
  listBox_3.SetSelected(selectedItem, true);
}
```

***Edit per OP comment…***

I am still not following what the requirements are, however, if you want all the `ListBoxes` to have the “same selected INDEXES” in each `ListBox`, then the code below may help.

One possible issue you may have with your current solution is a possible circular reference. Example, In the `listBox_1_SelectedIndexChanged` code, there is line of code…

```
listBox_2.SetSelected(count, true);
```

… this sets the selected index in list box 2 which will fire the `listBox_2_SelectedIndexChanged` event. Then… inside that event code you have the code…

```
listBox_1.SetSelected(count, true);
```

… which will fire the list box 1 event “again.”

It should be obvious that this may create an infinite circular reference where each event simply calls the other event and never ends.

Given that the code in the event needs to possibly “set” an index in one of the other `ListBoxes`, then it may be necessary to turn-off/unsubscribe the list box from its `SelectedIndexChanged` event before the code sets the index and then turn-on/re-subscribe to the event after the index has been set.

Therefore in the solution below, Since the same event is used for ALL three `ListBoxes`, the code turns-off/un-subscribes from each `ListBox` event before the code starts, and then turns-on/re-subscribes to the events when done.

In addition, as @zaggler correctly notes, checking if the `ListBox` actually HAS an index of the given value, it becomes necessary to check that the index is in a valid range before setting the index to avoid an index out of bounds exception.

```
private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  listBox_1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(listBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
  listBox_2.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(listBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
  listBox_3.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(listBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
  ListBox lb_1 = (ListBox)sender;
  ListBox lb_2;
  ListBox lb_3;
  switch (lb_1.Name) {
    case "listBox_1":
      lb_2 = listBox_2;
      lb_3 = listBox_3;
      break;
    case "listBox_2":
      lb_2 = listBox_1;
      lb_3 = listBox_3;
      break;
    default:
      lb_2 = listBox_1;
      lb_3 = listBox_2;
      break;
  }
  lb_2.ClearSelected();
  lb_3.ClearSelected();

  foreach (int selectedItem in lb_1.SelectedIndices) {
    if (selectedItem < lb_2.Items.Count) {
      lb_2.SetSelected(selectedItem, true);
    }
    if (selectedItem < lb_3.Items.Count) {
      lb_3.SetSelected(selectedItem, true);
    }
  }
  listBox_1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
  listBox_2.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
  listBox_3.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

Comment: John - the code is being called at 
listBox_1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Then the code i posted should work.

Comment: It did. ClearSelected() was what I was missing. Thanks John

Comment: @JNL you weren't missing the `ClearSelected`, your conditions were backwards.

Comment: @zaggler  - Can you help out with the edit in the question.
How do I replicate the behavior when the user selects the items in ListBox 2/ ListBox 3

Comment: @JohnG - Any suggestions?

Comment: @JNL … Well… I am somewhat confused by the requirement… if changing ANY ONE of the three `ListBoxes` changes the other `ListBoxes` to show the same selected items… then why bother with three different list boxes? Wouldn’t one `ListBox` accomplish the same thing? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: @JohnG - I see what you are saying, but in this case all the three listboxes represent some different data, like for example: DataA, DataB, DataC which are totally different...
Hence need the flexibility of 3 listboxes. and DataC can be modified/updated by the user.

So for Data A and DataB - DataC can vary..

Comment: Hmmm… Sorry but I am still not following your logic. If all three List boxes contain the same “selected” items, which it appears you are wanting to do… then I am not understanding “when” they would be “different.” You state that… _” … and DataC can be modified/updated by the user.”_ …? Wouldn’t this change the other list boxes to the same selected values as per your requirement? Do you want all the list boxes to be the same ONLY IF list box 1 or 2 are changed? And if list box three (3) is changed, then leave the other list boxes as they are?

Comment: @JohnG - So ListBox 1 and 2 wont change. Data in ListBox 3 can be changed/modified.

Comment: I mean no disrespect; however it seems to me that you are contradicting yourself. Can you give 3 examples… 1) an example of what is supposed to happen when the user selects an item in list box 1… 2) an example of what is supposed to happen when the user selects an item in list box 2… 3) an example of what is supposed to happen when the user selects an item in list box 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237883/discussion-between-jnl-and-johng).

Comment: @JohnG - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466252/select-deselect-multiple-items-in-multiple-listboxes

Maybe this post will make things more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Here Selection of items in LB1 should control the selection in LB2 and LB3. Now, since Item 2 and 3 are selected in LB1 - items 2 and 3 should be selected in LB2 and LB3 as well. But that's not what's happening.

I would recommend looping through all items of `listBox_1`...

```
for (int idx = 0; idx <= listBox_1.Items.Count - 1; idx++)
            {
                if (listBox_1.GetSelected(idx))
                {
                    if (idx <= listBox_2.Items.Count)
                        listBox_2.SetSelected(idx, true);
                    if (idx <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                        listBox_3.SetSelected(idx, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (idx <= listBox_2.Items.Count)
                        listBox_2.SetSelected(idx, false);
                    if (idx <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                        listBox_3.SetSelected(idx, false);
                }
            }
```

Please note, I put a check as well to make sure the index would exist, otherwise it could throw an error if the index doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your help @zaggler.

Comment: @JNL welcome, I would check if the index's exist if using JohnG answer, otherwise it will throw an exception.