# Select / Deselect Multiple items in multiple listboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I am trying to implement a multiple items select in multiple listboxes. Is this possible?

Requirements:

1. When user selects an item in ListBox1 - items in ListBox2 and ListBox3 should be selected.
2. When user deselects and item in ListBox1 - Items in ListBox2 and ListBox2 should be deselected.
   I am able to achieve this on LB1.

**Same behavior 1 and 2 should repeat for ListBox2 and ListBox3.
I am having difficulty here.**

[image]

I have the code below - but of course it runs into stackoverflow exception. What am I missing?

```
 private void listBox_1_SelectedIndexChanged_(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    int userSelectedIndex = listBox_1.Items.Count;
    if (listBox_1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < listBox_1.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            // Determine if the item is selected.
            if (listBox_1.GetSelected(count) == true)
            {
                if (count <= listBox_2.Items.Count)
                    listBox_2.SetSelected(count, true);
                if (count <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                    listBox_3.SetSelected(count, true);
            }
            else if (listBox_1.GetSelected(count) == false)
            {
                // Select all items that are not selected.
                if (count <= listBox_2.Items.Count)
                    listBox_2.SetSelected(count, false);
                if (count <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                    listBox_3.SetSelected(count, false);
            }
        }
   }
}


private void listBox_2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    int userSelectedIndex = listBox_2.Items.Count;
    if (listBox_2.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < listBox_2.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            // Determine if the item is selected.
            if (listBox_2.GetSelected(count) == true)
            {
                if (count <= listBox_1.Items.Count)
                    listBox_1.SetSelected(count, true);
                if (count <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                    listBox_3.SetSelected(count, true);
            }
            else if (listBox_2.GetSelected(count) == false)
            {
                // Select all items that are not selected.
                if (count <= listBox_1.Items.Count)
                    listBox_1.SetSelected(count, false);
                if (count <= listBox_3.Items.Count)
                    listBox_3.SetSelected(count, false);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the reason you're getting a stack overflow exception is because when you're updating the selected index from one listbox, to another, you're invoking the same event handler constantly in a loop, to prevent this, you can add a field something like: `_isUpdating` and inside of the Event Handlers, check if you are currently updating, if so, return from the event, if not, then process the event, you can then set `_isUpdating` to `true` before you make any changes to other listboxes and set it to `false` when you are complete.

Comment: I noticed though that you are using the `Count` of the `Items` and as the `userSelectedIndex` which will always be the same then doing nothing with it, then looping through every index to check if it's selected `<=` the other listbox item count, which in this case is always true as you have the same number of `items` in your `listboxes`.

Comment: In your question, can you be more specific about what you are requiring? As you stated: `"When user selects an item in ListBox1 - items in ListBox2 and ListBox3 should be selected."` is this based on the Index or a different condition? If it is based on index, please check the Answer I have provided which avoids the Stack Overflow Exception and also selects the item in the other listboxes according to the index

Comment: Don't use three ListBoxes, but a DataGridView instead.

Answer (score 0):

This field is used to avoid Stack Overflow Exceptions.

```
private bool _isUpdating;
```

I am also using the `SelectedValueChanged` event instead of `SelectedIndexChanged` but it should still work, here is the 3 different checkboxes (this could be improved by refactoring how it handles which listbox to update)

```
private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this._isUpdating)
    {
        //// Prevent Stack Overflow by exiting out
        return;
    }

    var selectedIndexes = this.listBox1.SelectedIndices;
    this._isUpdating = true;

    this.listBox2.SelectedItems.Clear();
    this.listBox3.SelectedItems.Clear();

    foreach (int index in selectedIndexes)
    {
        //// Listbox2
        var foundItem = this.listBox2.Items[index];
        this.listBox2.SelectedItems.Add(foundItem);

        //// Listbox3
        var foundItem2 = this.listBox3.Items[index];
        this.listBox3.SelectedItems.Add(foundItem2);
    }

    this._isUpdating = false;
}

private void listBox2_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this._isUpdating)
    {
        //// Prevent Stack Overflow by exiting out
        return;
    }

    var selectedIndexes = this.listBox2.SelectedIndices;
    this._isUpdating = true;

    this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
    this.listBox3.SelectedItems.Clear();

    foreach (int index in selectedIndexes)
    {
        //// Listbox1
        var foundItem = this.listBox1.Items[index];
        this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Add(foundItem);

        //// Listbox3
        var foundItem2 = this.listBox3.Items[index];
        this.listBox3.SelectedItems.Add(foundItem2);
    }

    this._isUpdating = false;
}

private void listBox3_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this._isUpdating)
    {
        //// Prevent Stack Overflow by exiting out
        return;
    }

    var selectedIndexes = this.listBox3.SelectedIndices;
    this._isUpdating = true;

    this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
    this.listBox2.SelectedItems.Clear();

    foreach (int index in selectedIndexes)
    {
        //// Listbox1
        var foundItem = this.listBox1.Items[index];
        this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Add(foundItem);

        //// Listbox2
        var foundItem2 = this.listBox2.Items[index];
        this.listBox2.SelectedItems.Add(foundItem2);
    }

    this._isUpdating = false;
}
```

Which as stated previously, avoids the `Stack Overflow Exception` and ensures that selecting / deselecting an item in the `Listbox` at a given `index` will also select the item at the other `listboxes index`.